# adding elements in a list on specific ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The code has been bugging me for hours and I have made several abortive efforts trying to make the code work.

What I would like my code to do is the following:

Two inputs, 'numerical_representation' and 'names' is entered into console.
Then, certain number of elements in 'names' will be summed according to the value in the numerical representation.

```
>>> numerical_representation = (4, 6, 5, 11)
>>> names = (4, 16, 10, 17, 4, 15, 6, 4, 14, 7, 17, 9, 6, 27, 9, 1, 12, 0, 8, 20, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3)
```

for example, since we first have 4 in 'numerical representation'
4, 16, 10, 17 in 'names' will be added and return 47.

then we have 6 in 'numerical representation' the next consecutive elements 4, 15, 6, 4, 14, 7 in 'names' will be added and return 50.

In the end, my goal is to return the 'value_list' as
[47, 50, 68, 55]

Below is what I have so far.

```
value_list = []    
for i in numerical_representation:
    sum_value = sum(names[:i])
    value_list.append(sum_value)
return value_list
```

however, this would return [47, 66, 62, 106]. I believe this is happening because the for iterator keeps iterating from the beginning of the 'names'.

How should I proceed?

Comment: What happens is you have [4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4]? What is the expected output?

Comment: I believe you should expect `[47, 50, 68, 55]` as output,

Comment: @DanielMesejo with numerical_representation =  [4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4] and names = (4, 16, 10, 17, 4, 15, 6, 4, 14, 7, 17, 9, 6, 27, 9, 1, 12, 0, 8, 20, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3)

Comment: @VAnon I mean numerical_representation = (4, 6, 5, 11)  and names = (4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4) ?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I will have my code assert and return error for such case

Comment: @VAnon I mean numerical_representation = (4, 6, 5, 11) and names = (4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4) why does it returns an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One minor addition will do:

```
for i in numerical_representation:
    sum_value = sum(names[:i])  # since you slice from the beginning ...
    value_list.append(sum_value)
    names = names[i:]  # ... insert this line to move forward
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than my solution but does destroy the tuple/list being operated on which may not be desirable.

Comment: @TBurgis No it doesn't. It does rebind the local variable `names`, but that won't do much harm, as the function returns right after the loop. The list/tuple object that may have been passed to the function will be completely unbothered.

Answer (score 0):

> "however, this would return [47, 66, 62, 106]. I believe this is
>   happening because the for iterator keeps iterating from the beginning
>   of the 'names'."

you have already figured the issue, you just need to be pointed in the right direction
try `while` loop instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the offset from each operation to set the start position:

```
value_list = [] 
start = 0
for i in numerical_representation:
    vals = names[start:start+i]
    sum_value = sum(vals)
    print(vals," sum to ",sum_value)
    value_list.append(sum_value)
    start = start + i
```